# sending signals of texts in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am writing a GUI Program with pyqt. I wrote its frame, now I want to write in the `LineEdit` and get it in to my program and do some work on it. I know I should work with signals but I couldn't find its functions. How should I write it?

After that I want to show the results of changing it the `TextEdit` box. How is that possible?

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class Rss(QtGui.QWidget):

  def __init__(self):
        super(Rss,self).__init__()
        self.resize(350,200)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle("Rss Reader")
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("OK",self)
        btn.setGeometry(300,40,40,20)
        lbl = QtGui.QLabel("insert the site here :",self)
        lbl.setGeometry(10,10,100,20)
        txt = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        txt.setGeometry(120,10,220,20)
        res = QtGui.QLabel("The Result Is :",self)
        res.setGeometry(10,60,100,20)
        result = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        result.setGeometry(10,80,330,100)
        self.show()

  def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
rss = Rss()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documenation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html) you'll find all the available signals there. You'll just need to add a method to your class that should do the work and connect them in `__init__`:

```
txt.editingFinished.connect(self.do_the_work)
```

You'll probably also want to keep a reference to the `txt` widget (replace `txt` with `self.txt`...), so you can easily look up the new value...